# Update JMeter when testing

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to update the script and refreshing when doing testing ?  eg, in a long load test, I need update a parameter and the test will pick it up during the run.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options:

1. Use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) for the value you want to update. The property value can be amended using i.e. [Beanshell server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server)
2. Use [external SQL database and JMeter's JDBC test elements](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter) for reading the data from there. In this case you can amend the data using [SQL UPDATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) statements
3. Use i.e. [Redis Data Set](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RedisDataSet/) plugin, in this case you will be able to update the data in Redis and JMeter will pick up new values

Comment: for item 2, what about a CSV file ?  Possible ?

Comment: If you're using [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) and amend CSV file externally - it will start picking new values on next iteration of each virtual user